# MySQL query with condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table of the form:

```
    id | error 1 | error 2 | error 3 | error 4 |
    --------------------------------------------
     1 |    1    |    0    |    0    |    1    |
    -------------------------------------------
     2 |    0    |    0    |    0    |    0    |
```

The id is the primary key and the errors are boolean columns.
Is there a way where I can fetch the IDs of the rows, if any of the error is 1 as true and false if all the errors are zero.

Comment: Perhaps with a WHERE clause?

Comment: Can the error columns have NULL's?

Comment: See normalization - or store the string, e.g: 1001 - or store the decimal representation, eg. 9

Comment: error column is by default 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select id,case when error1+error2+error3+error4 > 0
                then 1
                else 0
            end as error 
from Table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, case when error1 + error2 + error3 + error4 > 0 
                then 1
                else 0
           end as result
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM "your table name"
WHERE error 1 = 1
OR error 2 = 1
OR error 3 = 1
OR error 4 = 1
OR error 5  = 1
```